# Google Chrome Extension Not Displaying my ICON (Selenium Mode, NO GOOGLE WEBSTORE)

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to add the icon to my Extension, but it shows up as a puzzle piece. Has anyone encountered this problem? I'm not using google webstore, I'm using selenium, python and chrome driver.

[image]

```
            "browser_action" : {
                "default_icon": {
                    "16": "images/icon16.png",
                    "24": "images/icon24.png",
                    "32": "images/icon32.png"
                    }
            },
            "icons": { 
                "16": "images/icon16.png",
                "24": "images/icon24.png",
                "32": "images/icon32.png"
            },
```

Comment: Either the path is incorrect or it's actually the new extension menu, not your extension. It's impossible to tell without trying the real extension zip.

Comment: @wOxxOm clearly you are not experience with creating chrome extensions with python. If the path is not correct, then an exceptions is raised and identified as not path found. In other words it will not even start the extension...

Comment: Well, I guessed wrong. Without more info or the actual zip I'm afraid this is all you'll get... It can be even a bug in Chrome.